# My content is running off the bottom of my page

Tags: javascript, html, css, pagination, height

I am updating the webstore on my site to Ecwid. Since I used the Intuit Sitebuilder to build my site the page is a fixed size. I added a place holder in Sitebuilder to hold the script for the Ecwid store. However, some of the pages of my store run off of the bottom of the screen. I have contacted both Ecwid and Sitebuilder for help with this with no luck.

I need my store to be no longer than 1000px high and in the event one of the pages of the script is longer it will have a scrollbar to the left. Can someone please help me?

Here is a link to see what I am talking about: [*Dip Wizard Hydrographic Dip Kit Store*](http://www.dipwizard.com/new-store.html#!/~/product/category=4409263&id=18882021).

Comment: Aside: turn off that silly right-click interceptor if you're the one that put it there. There is exactly nobody out there to steal your intellectual property who's also unaware of the "Save page as..." function. What it has achieved is annoy me as I tried to poke at your CSS to see what could be done about it.

Comment: Sorry, it is turned off now. The owner of the site wanted it there so nobody could steal their images....crazy right

Comment: Explain to him that absolutely everyone that visits their website technically already stole them :D

Comment: Anyway, it seems like the height is set absolutely all over the place, so that's a no-go. (I wanted to see if you could just disable the absolute height on the element that sets is, and see whether the layout will survive the change. Seeing as the height is set on many, many elements, this doesn't seem practical.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to edit both html and css of your site:

**html:**
inside a div with id "element50", there's a div without an id. This is the container that you're worried about. You need to give this div an id, for example -

```
<div id="productInfo">
```

**css:** Then in your css - add these rules

```
#productInfo {
  margin-top: 25px;
  max-height: 1045px;
  overflow-x: hidden;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}
```

If this is very urgent and you can't find where to add/edit your css, you can add it in the html itself:

```
<div style="margin-top: 25px; max-height: 1045px; overflow-x: hidden; overflow-y: scroll;
```

But this is not recommended and should be replaced with proper css in the near future.

Comment: You could also use `#element50 > div` in case the HTML isn't modifiable easily. (As could be the case with a website generated by a third party tool.)

Comment: Actually the css above can simply be added to #element50's css and it should work properly

Comment: Thank You!!! I have been working on this problem for days and couldn't figure out where the error was

Comment: Next time use firebug. It will allow you to easily see the behavior of each part of your site and test what happens when you change stuff (like css). This is how I solved your problem

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly you want a scrollbar where the content is over 1000px, then i guess you should type in your css {overflow-y:scroll;} on your content element.